# How to run mysql in a command prompt using AutoIt?

Tags: mysql, command-line, cmd, autoit

I tried to run a command prompt and log in into mysql.

```
Run(@ComSpec & ' /k' & 'cd'&' '&@ScriptDir&'/mysql/bin')
```

this works perfectly. But When I add the `mysql` command like below, it doesn't work. It displays a *'path not found'* error message:

```
Run(@ComSpec & ' /k' & 'cd'&' '&@ScriptDir&'/mysql/bin/mysql u- root -p')
```

I would appreciate if anyone could show me the correct way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change your directory (`cd`) when you want to actually execute a program. The error message tells you, there is no directory `@ScriptDir/mysql/bin/mysql` - and there isn't. The directory `@ScriptDir/mysql/bin/` most likely exists and there most likely is an executable `mysql` inside...

So just use two commands separated by `;` instead:

```
Run(@ComSpec & ' /k' & 'cd ' & @ScriptDir & '/mysql/bin; mysql -u root -p')
```

You need to separate between the `cd` and the actual call of `mysql`. And you'd propably want to correct `u-` to `-u`.